# Undefined columns selected in mediate R

Tags: r, mediator, plm

I'm currently facing a problem estimating the mediation effect with function `mediate` from R package `mediation`.

I'm running three panel regressions with `plm` from R package `plm`:

```
TERR1_us <- plm(log(POLSTAB+1) ~ log(US+1) +  RDURAB + DEMOC +  log(POP+1) +MUS, data = US, index = c('NUMBER', "YEAR"), model = 'within', effect = "individual")

TERR2_us<- plm(log(TERROR+1) ~ log(US+1) + RDURAB + DEMOC +log(POP+1)+ MUS, data = US, index = c('NUMBER', "YEAR"), model = 'within', effect = "individual")

TERR3_us  <- plm(log(POLSTAB+1) ~ log(US+1) +  RDURAB + DEMOC +log(POP+1)+MUS +log(TERROR+1),  data = US, index = c('NUMBER', "YEAR"), model = 'within', effect = "individual")
```

To test the mediations significancy I run a bootstrapping test.

```
results_terr_us <- mediate(TERR2_us, TERR_us, treat="US", mediator="TERR",
                   boot=TRUE, sims=100)
```

Unfortunately, I always get the error message *Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , "US") : undefined columns selected*

Both models have the same number of observations. I don't think there are any commas that I set wrong.

Comment: Function `mediate` is not in base R. Which package are you using for that? Likely, this package does not cater for objects as produced by `plm`.

Comment: I use the mediation package. I thought about the problem with plm aswell, though I used lm and it also didnt work.

Comment: Try to have the `log()` already in your data and not via formula - maybe the package cannot cope with this specification in the formula (just a guess).